# SSRS > Need value only for specific items

Tags: reporting-services

Using 5 digit account codes from 00000 - 30000, I only need to report on codes that start with 02xxx through 16xxx. I have tried the following without success:

```
=if (Fields!JE_Major.Value > 01%,
And (Fields!JE_Major.Value < 17%,
then (Fields!JE_Amount.Value,)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just create a column in the SQL that highlights that column and then all you have to do is refer to the field value in SSRS or you could always write a where clause into your SQL too.